# Last digit of sum of squares of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: c++, sum, fibonacci

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int previous_fibonacci_last_digit(unsigned long long m) {
int previous = 0, current = 1;
for (unsigned long long i = 2; i <= m; i++) {
    int tmp_previous = previous;
    previous = current;
    current = ((tmp_previous % 10) + (current % 10)) % 10;

   return current;
}

int last_digit(unsigned long long n) {
     int lastDigit = ( previous_fibonacci_last_digit(n) * ( ( previous_fibonacci_last_digit(n) + previous_fibonacci_last_digit(n - 1) ) % 10 ) ) % 10 ; // found the last digit of the sum of squares of n fib numbers

     return lastDigit;
  }
```

To find the last digit of sum of squares of n fib numbers I found that the sum can be written as F(n) {F(n) + F(n-1)} and I was implementing it for large values.
When I used long long int my program crashed at n = 260548 so I changed it to unsigned long long int and now my program is crashing at n = 519265.

I tried debugging it by seeing if the loop goes till 500000 by adding a cout in the `previous_Fibonacci_last_digit()` function but I found that the loop is not even running till 500000 when n = 519265. I am just storing the last digit of each Fibonacci numbers so I don't think that there is any integer overflow in it.

Edit - Instead of using arrays,  now after using variables to store the last digit the program works fine but using it for n = 1234567890, it takes alot of time.

Comment: Or by the large array `int fib1[m]` Why do you need an array, large numbers, or recursion? Just work with the last digit all the time.

Comment: The whole point of these exercises is for you to realize that you don't need to keep the entire number around.  All you need is the last digit, *at each stage of the computation*.  Remember, (a + b) mod 10 = (a mod 10) + (b mod 10), and a*b (mod 10)  = (a mod 10)*(b mod 10).  So after every addition and every multiplication, do `v %= 10;`.

Comment: Try to use `std::vector`. `int fib[m]` is a non-standard extension and if memory serves, will be allocated in the stack, where memory is quite limited.

Comment: There are two observations that can help you. First, to compute f_i you only need f_{i-1} and f_{i-2}. Second (a+b) mod x = ((a mod x) + (b mod x)) mod x. If you use these together you will only be limited by you own patience.

Comment: You also don't need any arrays at all.  All you need are the last two values in the sequence.  So all of the comments about how you allocate your arrays shouldn't even be applicable if you've coded it properly.  It should take constant memory.

Comment: @TomKarzes I did what you asked and instead of using arrays I used variables and now the program is not crashing but when using it for the test case of n = 1234567890,  it takes a lot of time. And yes I stored only the last digit in those variables.

Comment: Well, if you run it for 1234567890 iterations, it's nor surprising it will take a long time!  If you want to be able to handle really large iteration counts, you can note that the sequence will repeat over time:  All you really need to know to continue it are the values of the last digits of the previous two terms.  So there are only 10*10 = 100 possibilities.   So for each such pair, you can determine the result when you iterate 10, 100, 1000, etc. times.  You can obtain a logarithmic time reduction that way.

Comment: For instance, for each 10x10 pair of digits, save the result of going out 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc. iterations.  Each one builds on the next:  To get 1000, go out 100 10 times, for each possible pair of digits.  Then to solve e.g. 1234, it's just the composition of 1000, 2x100, 3x10, and 4x1.  Just make sure the iteration count doesn't exceed an unsigned long long.

Comment: Thanks. I used the fact that last digits repeat at n=60 and now the program is calculating even 18 digit numbers in no time.

Answer (score 4):

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int fib(long long num ){
    int pre=0,cur=1;
    num = num %60;
    if(num==0){
        return 0;}
    else if (num == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
    for (int i =2; i<=num; i++){
        int temp = (pre+cur)%60;
        pre = cur;
        cur = temp;
        // cout<<pre<<"\n"<<cur<<"\n";
    }
    }
    
    return(cur); 
}

int main() {
    long long n = 0;
    cin >> n;
    int a = fib(n);
    int b = fib(n+1);
    
    cout<<(a*b)%10;
    
    
}
```

the sum of squares of up to any Fibonacci numbers can be calculated without explicitly adding up the squares.

As you can see

F1^2+..Fn^2 = Fn*Fn+1

Now to calculate the last digit of Fn and Fn+1, we can apply the Pisano period method

the last digit can be calculated by %10 and the Pisano period for mod 10 is 60. so, % 60 is used in the code directly...

Comment: I have implemented your solution but interestingly it computes a wrong value for the 239th Fibonacci number.

Comment: can you recheck your code? the `num = num %60;` seems to be wrong because if I give a number 60 or a multiple of 60 then it returns 0 but I may be wrong I'm not well versed in mathematical applications

Answer (score 1):

**Code in Python**

```
def pisano_num_mod10(n):
   previous, current = 0, 1
   n=n%60 #num mod 10 gives 60 repeatations in Pisano Series.. Check Wikipedia by searching for Pisano Series to get more Info
   if (n == 0): 
       return 0
   elif (n == 1): 
       return 1
   else:
       for _ in range(2,n+1):
           previous, current= current, (previous + current)%60
       return current
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    print(pisano_num_mod10(n)*pisano_num_mod10(n+1)%10)
```

Output:

```
if n=7 
pisano_num_mod10(n) returns 13
pisano_num_mod10(n+1) returns 21
It Prints 13*21%10=3
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my solution as well, which is very similar to the two of the solutions above. On the other hand, I will try to provide explaining as much as possible and I do one step differently, and depending on that difference my code got through all the tests.

The first equation to consider is that:
[image: F_N * F_N+1]

Hence instead of calculating a Fibonacci squares in each step (which take too long as can be predicted) we only need nth and (n+1)th Fibonacci values.

But also, it is unpractical to calculate the values that are higher than the Pisano period (which is simply the period that the remainder value repeats itself). Since we are only looking for the last digit, we can consider the problem as the module 10 of the calculated square sum of the Fibonacci values. And since Pisano period for modulo 10 is 60, we can use this value here.

That is why, for any given input number of n, if we take the modulo 60 of n and calculate the sum of the squares, we would decrease the computational time effectively.

And at the end, by taking the modulo 10 of the calculated value, we can return the last digit. Here is the code;

```
def last_digit_of_the_sum_of_squares_of_fibonacci_numbers(n):
   

    if n <= 1: #Check if the input value is too small
        return n

    n = n%60 #If not, take the mod60 of the input


    pre = 0 #First value of the Fibonacci series
    curr = 1 #Second value of the Fibonacci series
    for i in range(2, n+2): #Iterate until n+2, since we are looking for F_N + F_{N+1}
        pre, curr = curr, (pre+curr) #Calculate the current Fibonacci value

    return (pre*curr)%10 #return the mod10
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to devise a formula.
if you see the sum of sqaure in a series - 0,1,2(1+1),6(1+1+4),15(6+9),40,104,273,714,...

you will notice, that the last digit of any number element in the series will be in the following formula - Fn = (((Fn-1 + Fn-2)x2) - Fn-3)%10

for example - to find the last digit of F7 - ((104 + 40)x2) - 15=273%10 = 3

Here's the code:-

```
static int fiboSumOfSquaresLastDigit(int num)
        {
            int[] fibo = new int[num+1]; 
            fibo[0]=0; 
            fibo[1]=1; 
            fibo[2]=2;

            for(int i=3; i<=num; i++)
            {
                fibo[i]= (((fibo[i-1]+fibo[i-2])*2) - fibo[i-3])%10; 
            }
            return fibo[num];
        }
```